# NMaximize and Conditional Loop

Tags: mathematical-optimization, procedural-programming

I have developed the following code that simulates a process that decays over time and then returns to its initial state periodically.

When I pass a list of random integers in the interval $(1,0)$ as arguments, the function behaves as I expect it to.

However, when NMaximize calls the function, I get the following error:

> NMaximize::nnum: The function value -1000 - 19 If[a[21] == 1,500, 1000] is not a number at {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], a[10], a[11], a[12], a[13], a[14], a[15], a[16], a[17], a[18], a[19], a[20]} = {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}. >>
>   
>   `The interesting part of the error is the complaint about`a[21]`; this variable doesn't exist unless the function is called by`NMaximize`.  The idea is that`NMaximize` will find integer, binary values for the parameters that will maximize the return value of the function.

My guess is that there is problem in how my function is being translated internally by `NMaximize`, but I am not not sure what to do at this point.

```
(*Assign Initial Values*)
Clear[f, i, a, vars, realconstraints, integerconstraints]
PeriodCapacityLoss = 10;
InitialCapacity = 1000;
OOSCapacity = 500;
AssymtoticCapacity = 200;
Periods = 20;
CurrentCapacity[1] = InitialCapacity;

(*Generate random series of cleaning flags*)
For[j = 1, j < Periods + 1, j++,
  RecoveryFlag[j] = RandomInteger[{0, 1}];
];

(*Function to simulate effect of capacity degredation and recovery*)
f[a_] := Module[{i},
  (* Set initial condition as clean *)  
  CurrentCapacity[1] = InitialCapacity;
  For[i = 2, i < Periods + 1, i++,
    CurrentCapacity[i] = 
      If[a[i] == 0 && a[i - 1] == 0, 
        CurrentCapacity[i - 1] - PeriodCapacityLoss, 
        If[a[i] == 1, OOSCapacity, InitialCapacity]
      ];
  ];
  Return[Total[Map[CurrentCapacity, Range[Periods]]]];
];

(*Pass random cleaning flags to degredation function and plot*)
Print[f[RecoveryFlag]];

ListLinePlot[Array[CurrentCapacity, Periods]]

(* Define the integer constraints *)
vars = Array[a, Periods];
realconstraints = And @@ Map[Greater[2, #, 0]&, vars];
integerconstraints = Append[realconstraints, Element[vars, Integers]];

(* 
  Find the value of the recovery flag that maximizes capacity across the 
  time window
*)
NMaximize[{f[a], integerconstraints}, vars, Method->{"DifferentialEvolution"}]
```

Comment: Possibly `NMaximize` will be less inclined to sulk if the function is a "black box", that is, only evaluating for explicitly numeric arguments. That can be attained via e.g. `f[a_?NumberQ] := ...`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau But in this sample, `a` is only a `Head`…

Comment: @xzczd I had missed that. Would be better to make it a vector, say, or an explicit function.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Aha, 8 years passed and now I'm able to figure out what's wrong with OP's original attempt. The problem can be boiled down to the following:

**Why does an `a[21]` appear in the warning message?**

This is actually a matter of evaluation order. Just observe the output of the following sample:

```
Clear[a, i];
i = 1;
If[a[i] > 0, 1, If[a[i] < 2, 4]]
(* If[a[1] > 0, 1, If[a[i] < 2, 4]] *)
```

As we can see, there's an `a[i]` in 2nd `If[…]`, this is because `If` owns `HoldRest` attribute, so the `a[i]` inside 2nd `If[…]` is never evaluated.

"So what? This won't cause any problem, because `a[i]` will finally evaluate to `a[1]` at sometime! " Yes, if only the value of `i` never changes afterwards, but sadly it's not the case for OP's `f`: the value of `i` is changing in the `For` loop, which finally becomes `21`!

So, how to fix? Using `PiecewiseExpand` as shown below is of course a solution, but a more on-target solution is to adjust the evaluation order to make the `a[i]`s evaluate at proper timings, which can be done with `With`:

```
f[a_] := Module[{i},(*Set initial condition as clean*)
  CurrentCapacity[1] = InitialCapacity;
  For[i = 2, i < Periods + 1, i++, 
   CurrentCapacity[i] =(*PiecewiseExpand@*)
     With[{i = i}, 
      If[a[i] == 0 && a[i - 1] == 0, CurrentCapacity[i - 1] - PeriodCapacityLoss, 
       If[a[i] == 1, OOSCapacity, InitialCapacity]]];];
  Return[Total[Map[CurrentCapacity, Range[Periods]]]];]
```

You'll see some of the `i` becomes red, it's merely for warning. If you don't like it, just change the `With[…]` to `With[{ii = i},  If[a[ii] == 0 && a[ii - 1] == 0, CurrentCapacity[ii - 1] - PeriodCapacityLoss,  If[a[ii] == 1, OOSCapacity, InitialCapacity]]]`.

---

Maybe there're deeper reasons, but I can't figure it out right now: it seems that `NMinimize` doesn't like `If`. Add a `PiecewiseExpand` to the definition of `f` will fix the problem:

```
f[a_] := Module[{i},(*Set initial condition as clean*)
   CurrentCapacity[1] = InitialCapacity;
   For[i = 2, i < Periods + 1, i++, 
    CurrentCapacity[i] = 
      PiecewiseExpand@
       If[a[i] == 0 && a[i - 1] == 0, 
        CurrentCapacity[i - 1] - PeriodCapacityLoss, 
        If[a[i] == 1, OOSCapacity, InitialCapacity]];];
   Return[Total[Map[CurrentCapacity, Range[Periods]]]];];

vars = Array[a, Periods];
realconstraints = And @@ Map[Greater[2, #, 0] &, vars];
integerconstraints = Append[realconstraints, Element[vars, Integers]];

NMaximize[{f[a], integerconstraints}, vars, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}]
```

> {10500., {a[1] -> 1, a[2] -> 1, a[3] -> 1, a[4] -> 1, a[5] -> 1,
> a[6] -> 1, a[7] -> 1, a[8] -> 1, a[9] -> 1, a[10] -> 1, a[11] -> 1,
> a[12] -> 1, a[13] -> 1, a[14] -> 1, a[15] -> 1, a[16] -> 1,    a[17]
> -> 1, a[18] -> 1, a[19] -> 1, a[20] -> 1}}

Comment: All `PiecwiseExpand` seems to be doing here is defining a default value so the `If` statement doesn't remain unevaluated; e.g. providing 0 as the last argument of the last `If` gives the same fix.

Comment: @RonaldMonson Not the same. The maximum in my case is `10500`, but yours is `1000`. BTW I manage to figure out the root of OP's problem, check my edit.

Comment: I'm glad this seems to be sorted - I haven't gone through the details (my eyes glaze over when imperative algorithms are used these days - and indeed such bugs are an illustration of the superiority of functional solutions IMO). But the [broader point that led to this re-visiting remains](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/256606/2249): `PiecewiseExpand`'s transformations weren't strictly necessary in the light of a more straightforward re-factoring.

Comment: @RonaldMonson I'd say it's natural that `PiecewiseExpand` isn't necessary. (It doesn't even exist in programming languages like C, right? :D ) But at least in this case it provides a sweet alternative for fixing the problem. (`PiecewiseExpand@` is easier to type than `With[{i = i}, …]` in my opinion. )

Comment: I'd say it is problematic when `PiecewiseExpand` is used unnecessarily. It is potentially much more expensive given the rich transformation rules it contains. Don't get me wrong, I think it can be  a very powerful tool in mathematical settings (unlike other languages, indeed) and my original question was exploring if it could be used likewise beyond such settings. The issue seem to be that it is performing a dual role when applied to  procedural expressions, casting them into mathematical form *and* performing simplifications/expansions. Sometimes it is only the former that is intended.