# Use cases for PiecewiseExpand applied to If or Which?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, conditional

As indicated by its name, `PiecewiseExpand`'s most natural application is to `Piecewise` expressions but nonetheless, it is still documented as being applicable to (unevaluated) `If`, `Which` and `Switch` expressions. Has anyone ever had any experience of usefully applying `PiecewiseExpand` to these procedural-like conditionals?

Applications like

```
Clear@f;

f[x_] := Which[
   EvenQ@x, "even",
   LessThan[10]@x, "lessThan10",
   GreaterThan[20]@x, "greaterThan20"];

PiecewiseExpand[f[x], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Integers]
```

[image]

don't expand as expected in more general programming contexts whereas `PiecewiseExpand`'s simplifying engine seems more apt in mathematical settings in which case `Piecewise` then seems more natural.

```
Clear@f;

f[x_] := Piecewise[{
    {"even", Mod[x, 2] == 0},
    {"lessThan10", x < 10},
    {"greaterThan20", x > 20}}];

PiecewiseExpand[f[x], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Integers]
```

[image]

Comment: Just search [piecewiseexpand if](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=piecewiseexpand+if) in this site and you'll see a number of related answers.

Comment: I did do this as well as search Mathematica's internal files for any examples of `PiecewiseExpand` being effectively applied to `If`, `Which` or `Switch`. Could you perhaps provide a link or two?

Comment: Well, I myself use the combination of `PiecewiseExpand` and `If` (and in many cases `Simplify\`PWToUnitStep`) quite a bit, because for simple binary decision I found e.g. `PiecewiseExpand@If[x > 2, 1, 3]` is easier to code and cleaner than `Piecewise[{{1, x > 2}}, 3]`. For more info just check the link above.

Comment: As to the reason for transforming `If[…]` to `Piecewise[…]`, generally `Piecewise` is more robust for defining piecewise functions, see the following posts: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69066/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29610/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156913/1871

Comment: I don't see evidence of such robustness in the three links provided: the first link seems to produce identical output with `PiecewiseExpand` removed; the second link doesn't seem to need `PiecewiseExpand` as its role is in forcing a default value (achieved by putting a final 0 in the corresponding `If` statement) while in the third link the same output is generated by removing `PiecewiseExpand` after some minor re-factoring. Further, outside these, it seems SE posts very rarely use `PiecewiseExpand` on a conditional and when they do, it is to illustrate some documentation-like toy example.

Comment: At any rate, thanks for digging those up but I guess I'm looking more for some examples/idioms using more "control-flow-like" branching found in "general programming" rather than alternative, syntactical definitions of mathematical functions -- although this is admittedly a bit vague.

Comment: So, you're not that interested in arithmetic application of `If`, `Which`, `Switch`? Then I think it's better to clarify a bit in the body of question.

Comment: Well, yes and no, yes, mainly yes but no, not never no (I'll clarify in question in due course)

Comment: My memory, fwiw, of algebraic/functional `Piecewise` vs. control-flow/procedural `If` etc. is the robustness @xzczd refers to (in algebraic/numerical solvers) was more apparent in earlier versions. Over time, `PiecewiseExpand` has been added under the hood to the solvers because (I surmise) users did appreciate the difference between `Piecewise` and `If`.  I don't recall seeing someone use `Piecewise` to select, say, a method  subroutine depending option values. The confusion seems to be one-way.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Perhaps that is the chronology (I don't have any sense/data either way) but I would also say the original design intent seems to have been for these to both be interchangeable even if such interchangeably seems to have been sparingly realised save for some appreciative users. The problem is that to implement the interchangeability there is a tension between forcing evaluation (to avoid annoying `TrueQ` boilerplate) for control-flow usage and maintaining non-evaluation for mathematical/piecewise usage - a tension that comes home to roost when `PiecewiseExpand` is set to apply to ...

Comment: ... both. It seems that this tension is the main reason why the *Q functions are designed to always evaluate. I think there is potentially a way around this but alas at least with the current designs this seems baked in.

Comment: Some cases where they didn't seem to be interchangeable: [1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82613/how-to-compute-dsolve-or-ndsolve-for-kind-of-piece-wise-function#comment223641_82689)
[2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80953/4999)
[3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140451/4999) -- As for `*Q[]` functions, immediate T/F evaluation is useful. It's nice that one can predict when that's going to happen (except `EllipticNomeQ[]` or `LegendreQ[]`). One has to think about other approaches for use-cases in which immediate evaluation is problematic.

Comment: @MichaelE2 AFAICMO none of the 3 examples suggest a lack of interchangeability 1) is using `PiecewiseExpand` to control evaluation which could be handled using a `With` injection with `If` 2) in my latest Mma version the `If` and `Piecewise` versions work identically (although this might be later versions catching up as suggested) while in 3) the graphing issue seems to be related to and resolvable by options not any `Piecewise` casting/defining. Hence all these seem to be examples of ready interchangeability ...

Comment: ... There are a couple of examples of [differentiability](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173590/2249) and [statistical distributions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/256693/2249)  where `PiecewiseExpand` seems necessary although I tend to think these are bugs that will eventually be resolved to restore their interchangeability. As for "As for *Q[] functions, immediate T/F evaluation is useful. It's nice that one can predict when that's going to happen"; I wonder if this really is the case; 1) it creates angst/gotchas in several places (`Piecewise`/`Reduce` etc) 2) it is ...

Comment: ... not needed in conditional definitions or in say `Select` operations 3) Its covenant is [already broken in many places](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159896/2249) 4) it can lead to clear bugs in negative definitions like `SatisfiabilityQ@2` 5) Its definitiveness can be forced with `TrueQ` in conditionals or in the case of `If` with extra flexibility in its final argument. I imagine there are important use-cases for this T/F mandate (which also breaks the covenant of "lazy unevaluation" in a symbolic language) but I have to confess to struggling to come up with examples?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `EvenQ@x`*immediately* evaluates to `False`. As you note, if you replace this by `Mod[x,2]==0` then `PiecewiseExpand` works fine.

In my view, what you really need here is a *domain*, say adding `Evens` and `Odds`—just as `NonNegativeIntegers` and friends were added in 12.0—so that you can write `Element[x,Evens]` instead.

As a related example, instead of using `PrimeQ@n` we have a domain to work with: `Element[n,Primes]`.

Comment: +1 Ok, thanks for noticing that and which on further investigation had been [previously observed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110838/modk-2-0-versus-evenqk). Yes a domain `"Evens"` solution is a more literate one over `Mod` however the pathway it suggests portends large downstream "duplication"-one version of (potentially unevaluated) functions for `PiecewiseExpand` and another (never unevaluated) for the procedural conditionals. This seems less than ideal; note also the (potentially unevaluated) `Positive`, `Negative` `NonNegative`,`NonPositive` ...

Comment: ... This all stems from the idiom of `*Q` functions being "never unevaluated" which seems to me to be an unfortunate early design decision but that horse seems to have bolted ...